# download an entire picasa web album?

Tags: browser, download, photos, picasa

Someone sent me a link to their Picasa web album, and I want to download all the pictures.  I can do them one by one using right-click - Save Image, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ian is right, the exact method is [**documented in Picasa support**](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=39513).

If you don't want to install the entire desktop app, there is the open source [**Picasa Album Downloader**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/picasaalbumdown/) available for Windows, Mac, and Linux:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Picasa desktop app installed I know you can do this. You can get it at http://picasa.google.com/ -- once the app is installed: from the album view in your browser, where it shows you the thumbnails for all the pictures in the album, there's tab just below the title of the album that says "Download". Click that, you'll get a menu of choices. Choose "Download with Picasa" and it'll copy all the album down to your machine through the Picasa desktop app.